# Is there a way to play part of a .wav file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, wav

I'm making a music program and I want to be able to skip into songs, for example skipping to 30 seconds in.

I couldn't find a way to skip into a wav file, so I tried to take the wav file as a string, delete the first n seconds, then save that as a temporary file to play. But when I try to convert it back to a stream, or save the string directly as a file I get a string conversion error.

Is there a way to skip into a wav file or create a new, shorter wav file from an original?

```
    Sub CreateShorterFile(PercentOfScreen As Single)
        Dim NewFileName As String
        Dim SamplesToSkip As Integer
        For i = OpenFileDialog.FileName.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If OpenFileDialog.FileName(i) = "\" Then
                NewFileName = OpenFileDialog.FileName.Substring(i + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Using wavout As Stream = OpenFileDialog.OpenFile()
            Dim strReader As New StreamReader(wavout, Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim FileAsString As String = strReader.ReadToEnd
            SamplesToSkip = Math.Floor(PercentOfScreen * (FileAsString.Length - 40)) 'data tag occupies 37th-40th position, data starts at 40
            SamplesToSkip = SamplesToSkip - SamplesToSkip Mod 4
            Dim NewFileAsString As String = FileAsString.Substring(0, 40)
            NewFileAsString += FileAsString.Substring(SamplesToSkip + 40)
            Dim WavStream As New MemoryStream(NewFileAsString)

            Using fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create("output.wav")

                Dim buf(1024 * 8) As Byte
                Dim len As Integer

                Do
                    len = WavStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
                    If len = 0 Then Exit Do
                    fs.Write(buf, 0, len)
                Loop

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

The error message is

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "RIFFj{'
> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

On the line `Dim WavStream As New MemoryStream(NewFileAsString)`

EDIT: I have changed the code to never convert to a string, and it now successfully saves to a .wav file. When I open this .wav file manually outside of the program, it plays fine, but when trying to play this .wav file from my.computer.audio.play it is silent.
My.computer.audio.play works fine for other .wav files.

```
 Sub CreateShorterFile(PercentOfScreen As Single)
        Dim NewFileName As String
        Dim SamplesToSkip As Integer
        Dim SampleBytes() As Byte
        Dim fmtextra() As Byte
        Dim NewWavByte() As Byte
        Dim fmtExtraSize As Integer
        Dim fmtExtraSizeByte() As Byte
        For i = OpenFileDialog.FileName.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If OpenFileDialog.FileName(i) = "\" Then
                NewFileName = OpenFileDialog.FileName.Substring(i + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Using wavout As Stream = OpenFileDialog.OpenFile()
            SamplesToSkip = Math.Floor(PercentOfScreen * (wavout.Length - 44) / 2) 'data tag occupies 37th-40th position, data starts at 40
            SamplesToSkip = SamplesToSkip - SamplesToSkip Mod 4
            GC.Collect()
            Dim wavefile() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            GC.Collect()
            Dim MemoryStream As New MemoryStream(wavefile)
            Dim BinReader As New BinaryReader(MemoryStream)
            Dim ChunkID As Byte() = BinReader.ReadBytes(4)
            Dim FileSize As Integer = BinReader.ReadInt32()
            Dim MetaData As Byte() = BinReader.ReadBytes(8)
            Dim fmtSize As Integer = BinReader.ReadInt32()
            Dim MetaData2 As Byte() = BinReader.ReadBytes(16)
            If fmtSize = 18 Then
                fmtExtraSizeByte = BinReader.ReadBytes(2)
                fmtExtraSize = BitConverter.ToUInt16(fmtExtraSizeByte)
                fmtextra = BinReader.ReadBytes(fmtExtraSize)
            End If
            Dim DataID As Byte() = BinReader.ReadBytes(4)
            Dim DataSize As Integer = BinReader.ReadInt32()
            DataSize = DataSize - SamplesToSkip
            FileSize = DataSize + 36
            BinReader.ReadBytes(SamplesToSkip * 2)
            SampleBytes = BinReader.ReadBytes(MemoryStream.Length - MemoryStream.Position)
            If fmtSize = 18 Then
                NewWavByte = ChunkID.Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(FileSize).Concat(MetaData).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(fmtSize)).Concat(MetaData2).Concat(fmtExtraSizeByte).Concat(fmtextra).Concat(DataID).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(DataSize)).Concat(SampleBytes)).ToArray()
            Else
                NewWavByte = ChunkID.Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(FileSize).Concat(MetaData).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(fmtSize)).Concat(MetaData2).Concat(DataID).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(DataSize)).Concat(SampleBytes)).ToArray()
            End If
            Dim NewWav As Stream = New MemoryStream(NewWavByte)
            Using NewWav
                Using fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create("output.wav")
                    fs.Write(NewWavByte, 0, NewWavByte.Length)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\output.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub
```

Comment: See a [wav file specification](https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/wav/#:~:text=WAV%20File%20Header-,) You should read the header bytes and parse into appropriate values. The data comes after the header. Once you trim the data, you will also need to update the file size in the header before writing back.

Comment: @djv, how would you read the read the data that won't be changed? I can't read it as a string because that causes an error when I try to save it as a file.